# Is it assumed that Wizards find spells during adventures?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard, treasure

One of the main features of Wizards is that they can have vast numbers of spells in their Spell book.

I have not played in Adventure League games, nor run any of the Pre-built adventures, so have no experience of how frequently this may have been designed to happen.

Is it assumed that Wizard characters *will* find new spells during their adventures, or is gaining two per level seen as normal, and its a feature that they *can* get extra spells...

Comment: Related: [Does the number of spells at a Wizard's disposal affect game balance?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/91295)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on my experience, it's pretty rare to find a usable scroll.  I blame AL rules and/or DM obliviousness on the lack of new spells available to wizards.  I have had luck in trading with other wizard PCs for spells, using gold and downtime to copy their spells into his book.

as a result, my 3rd level wizard has about as many 1st level spells as are available.  And exactly 2 2nd level spells...

However, based off of the rules, yes, it is assumed that a wizard expands their spell repertoire by finding scrolls / spell books while adventuring.

Answer (score 11):

### Yes.

The PHB says:

> You might find other spells during your adventures. You could discover a spell recorded on a scroll in an evil wizard's chest, for example, or in a dusty tome in an ancient library.

Additionally:

Spell scrolls are listed on the random treasure tables in the DMG and the Monster Manual mentions that some monsters, such as a Lich may have "libraries of spellbooks".

It is also possible to simply buy them.  (For a value of "simply" that depends on how common wizards are in your setting).

Comment: I think the question was asking whether it's the *default assumption* that wizards will find spells during adventures, not whether it's a *thing that can happen*.

Comment: @user2357112 — Being listed on the default random treasure tables is probably the strongest bit of evidence in my answer to support my assertion.

Comment: @Quentin Looking in the DMG it gives number's for how many times a party gets a Treasure Hoard, and doing the math on the tables. I calculate that of the seven rolls on the CR 0-4 table that only equates to 2.1 scrolls received. maybe 50/50 chance being a wizard spell. So by my maths you are only likely  to find one scroll in the first 4 levels. Does this seem about right?